# Can Common Lisp type annotations result in unsound behavior?

Tags: types, common-lisp, declare

I know that if the safety setting is low, Common Lisp can use type annotations as optimization aids and are not checked. For example, this program runs and prints both the number and the string without any type errors. (I only get a type error in SBCL, when safety >= 1)

```
(declaim (optimize
           (speed 3)
           (safety 0)))

(defun f (x)
  (declare (type fixnum x))
  x)

(format t "1 ~A~%" (f 17))
(format t "2 ~A~%" (f "asd"))
```

I now wonder if its possible to create a program that does nasty things if safety is set to zero and type annotations are not respected. Things like casting from one type to another (like C type casts) and other kinds of undefined behavior.

So far, I haven't managed to find out an example that does that. I tried variations of this example that uses typed arrays but none of them resulted in typecasting behavior.

```
(declaim (optimize
           (speed 3)
           (safety 0)
           ))

(defun f ()
    (let ((arr (make-array '(5)
      :element-type 'fixnum
      :initial-contents (list 1 2 3 4 5))))
      (declare (type (vector fixnum 5) arr))
      (setf (aref arr 0) "hello")
      (aref arr 0)))

(format t "a1 ~A~%" (f))
```

In CLISP, this program prints "hello", without doing a typecast to int and in SBCL the program aborts with a SIMPLE-TYPE-ERROR error.

Is there a way to create a Common Lisp program that results in demons coming out of my nose if I don't respect my type declarations?

Comment: I do not if this is a demon, but in CCL your program prints: `a1 6614253635515`.

Comment: For SBCL the type inference knows the type of the locally-created values. sds's answer shows a good way to work around that.

Comment: @Xach: Can you make an example? Running sds's example on SBCL is giving me an `#(1 2 3) is not a LIST` error instead of the nonsense value that I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of examples with `safety 0` in sbcl:

```
CL-USER> (proclaim '(optimize (safety 0)))
; No value
```

## Out Of Bounds Read

```
CL-USER> (loop for i from 0 to 20 
              do (print (aref #(0) i)))

0 
0 
#(0) 
(I) 
I 
NIL 
(AREF #(0) I) 
NIL 
(PRINT (AREF #(0) I)) 
NIL 
#<unknown immediate object, lowtag=#b1001, widetag=#x59 {D59}> 
#<SB-KERNEL:LAYOUT for SB-KERNEL:LEXENV {10005F3C33}> 
NIL 
NIL 
NIL 
NIL 
NIL 
NIL 
NIL 
NIL 
NIL 
NIL
```

## Undefined Typecasting

```
CL-USER> (defun f (x y)
           (declare (fixnum x y))
           (+ x y))
F
CL-USER> (f t ())
537919538
```

In SBCL if you smell nasal demons you can restart the image and input `(sb-ext:restrict-compiler-policy 'safety 3)` (and maybe again with `'debug`, too) before loading the problematic code. With a little luck that will get you a nice condition instead of undefined behavior.

Comment: Out-of-bounds array reads are a good example of undefined behavior but doesn't really have to do with type annotations, which is what I am most curious about. Do you know if its possible to write a program that behaves differently with and without type annotations (assuming safety=0)

Comment: @hugomg `f` defined above signals a type error if you remove the type declaration and make the same call.

Comment: @hugomg We used the same function name -- I mean the `f` at the end of my example. Is that the sort of typecasting you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I wanted! I didn't notice it the first time around because I didn't pay much attention and thought it was part of the nonsense lines printed by the for loop.

Comment: SBCL demons: `(defun foo (x) (declare (optimize (safety 0)) (type cons x)) (car x))`, then `(foo 0)`.

Answer (score 4):

The Common Lisp standard says that there are type declarations. It does not really say what they do or what an implementation would do with them.

Purposes:

- generate type specific code
- run-time and/or compile-time type checking. This is mostly only been done by CMUCL, SBCL and SCL.

Let's say we have the operation:

```
(+ i 100)
```

By default it would be a generic `+`, which can handle all numeric types.

If we tell that `i` is a `fixnum` then

- the `+` operation can be fixnum specific

If additionally the return type is declared as a `fixnum`:

- it may not overflow into a bignum

If we additional tell the compiler that we want low `safety`, then the compiler will not generate runtime type checks.

What capabilities the compiler provides is not standardized. It can even fully ignore the type declaration.

If you have a compiler which supports type specific code (and there are many such compilers), safety is low and one provides an object of the wrong type at runtime, then it can have unwanted consequences. Including crashing the Lisp due to heap memory corruption.

Thus it is best to use low safety only on very small code regions and not on whole files or systems. Using declarations with `locally` helps.

SBCL (also SCL and CMUCL) is special, because it also treats type declarations as assertions for type checking.

Comment: About the "it may not overflow into a bignum", it actually may.  Your implementation may have argument-to-return type contagion, not unheard of, but it doesn't make it right.  For this effect, you should declare the type of the result, such as `(the fixnum (+ i 100))`, assuming `i` is already declared of type `fixnum`.

Comment: @PauloMadeira: yes, that makes more sense. I have changed the answer a bit.

Comment: Can you please provide me with an example that crashes or ends up with memory curruption? So far, all the code I tried behaved exactly the same with and without type declarations (which would kind of imply that the type declarations are useless)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the demons, but you *can* get a segfault, as I did 15+ years ago with CMUCL and something similar to this code:

```
(declaim (optimize (speed 3) (safety 0)))
(defun f (v)
  (declare (type (vector double-float) v))
  (loop for x in v sum x))
(f #(1 2 3))
```

Note that I promised the I will only pass `(vector double-float)` to `f` and then I gave it a `simple-vector` with `fixnum`s.